# How is String a reference type in Java?

Tags: java, string, reference

I understand that classes are reference types, for example I created the following class:

```
class Class {

String s = "Hello";

public void change() {
    s = "Bye";
} }
```

With the following code, I understand that `Class` is a reference type:

```
Class c1 = new Class(); 
Class c2 = c1; //now has the same reference as c1

System.out.println(c1.s); //prints Hello
System.out.println(c2.s); //prints Hello

c2.change(); //changes s to Bye

System.out.println(c1.s); //prints Bye
System.out.println(c2.s); //prints Bye
```

Now I want to do the same thing with a String, that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = s1; //now has the same reference as s1 right?

System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello
System.out.println(s2); //prints Hello

s2 = "Bye"; //now changes s2 (so s1 as well because of the same reference?) to Bye

System.out.println(s1); //prints Hello (why isn't it changed to Bye?)
System.out.println(s2); //prints Bye
```

Comment: You are confusing reference variable with object, and will want to read up on the difference.

Comment: Strings are immutable and whenever you "change" a string it actually just creates a new string and changes the reference to point at the new one.

Comment: s2 and s1 are not the same references. They're two different references that initially refer to the same String instance... until you do `s2 = "Bye"`.

Comment: The reference in java is not the same as C/C++. ```s1``` and ```s2``` are two reference refer to the same string ```Hello```. Once you change ```s2``` which means ```s2``` refers to a new string ```Bye``` while ```s1``` remains the same.

Comment: It kinda does work the exact same way in C. You can have a char* and point it at the same address as another char*, then point it at a different address. If you do that with string literals the syntax would look basically the same as what he's doing here.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't call your class `Class`, because the JDK already has a (fairly common used) class by that name. It can confuse people; if I see a class called `Class`, my default is to sure it's the JDK one.

Comment: Thanks! I know you shouldn't call your class `Class`, I just did it for this example but indeed even then it can be confusing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the first case you are calling a method to the referenced object, thus the referenced object changes, not the 2 references:

[image: method]

In the second case you are assigning a new object to the reference itself, which is then pointing to that new object:

[image: new object]

Answer (score 7):

This is because you are updating the reference of s2 and not s1. Lets see how your code got executed:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = s1;
```

A `Hello` literal string created in `String pool`, whose reference was then put to `s1`. Then in the second line `s2` also got the same reference.

[image]

By now, `s1` and `s2` are pointing to the same literal string in `String pool`.

Now when the below piece of code got executed.

Another, literal `Bye` got created in `String pool` and the reference was put in `s2`. Howoever, `s1` still has the old reference and hence is printing `Hello`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Again, the fact that strings are immutable is irrelevant. The bahavior would be exactky the same with mutable objects.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah agreed... Updated my answer... I am still not sure why I wrote immutable...Lol

Answer (score 0):

```
s2 = "Bye";
```

This is equivalent to creating a new String object and assigning its reference to `s2` (`s2 = new String("Bye");`) and hence `s1` and `s2` are different.

You are comparing the above with a method call like `c2.change()` which changes some internal field value.

In other words, `s2 = "Bye";` is equivalent to `Class c2 = new Class();` in your example. After `c1.change()`, you cannot expect, `c1` and `c2` to have the same value for field `s`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree that immutability is not the issue. I will reword it.

Comment: Not sure why there are still dv's as your answer is now correct

Answer (score -2):

Java is pass-by-value. If you are passing an object into method then you are accualy passing only value of this object, not the object itself and it's value remains the same

Comment: What does "the object itself" mean?

Comment: I meant that object is not an argument. Only obejct's value

Answer (score -3):

String s1="Hello";
String s2=s1;

When you do the change like,

s2="Bye";

**you are doing this**

s2 = new String("Bye");

**explicitly**.

Comment: No. "Bye" and new String("Bye") are not equivalent.

Comment: Yeah , i know this.Just to explain the concept

Comment: Then why does your answer say that doing `s2="Bye";` is doing `s2 = new String("Bye");`? Explain the concept without saying something wrong.

Comment: new will allocate seperate memory to the s2 instead of joining the string in string pool.

Comment: @JBNizet my bad!